# Automatically allow access to tables in postgres from a user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-migration

I have a Postgresql database for a web application.  The database is owned by a particular user on the system, let's say `foouser`.  As the owner, this user has full permissions on the database.

The server also has another user, let's say `webappuser`, which is the user under which the application server runs.  Instead of specifying a username and password in the web application's config file, I want to use "peer" authentication.  I have gotten the authentication to work properly, but I ran into the following issue.

When I created the `webappuser` role in Postgresql, I granted it `LOGIN` permission as well as `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE foo TO webappuser;` and within the database `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO webappuser;`.

The issue that I am having is with the table permissions.  Unlike MySQL which allows access by default to all tables if you have access to the database (a reasonable assumption in my opinion), Postgresql denies access to all of the tables even though permission has been given on the schema and the database.  In order to get around this, I have to explicitly grant permissions on all new tables, views, procedures, etc. that I create using `GRANT ALL ON TABLE table_name TO webappuser;` (and similarly for views, etc.).

It ends up that any time I run a database migration, I have to add the permissions to the database for the new tables that were created.  The problem is that I can't add this permission information to the migrations themselves because developer machines don't have that additional user.  In any case, that really looks like the wrong way of doing things.

How can I allow access to the database tables from this additional user without needing manual intervention every time a table, view, procedure, etc. is created?

*BONUS POINTS*: Is there a way to restrict the user's permission to only CRUD operations instead of full permissions and still do the whole thing automatically?

Comment: How do you do "database migration"? Is that a matter of running DDL scripts or do you pg_dump/pg_restore?

Comment: In general, do not grant `ALL` but grant specific privileges such as `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` for CRUD functionality.

Comment: @Patrick I'm using [Laravel's built-in migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) which create SQL statements. It's pretty similar to Rails migrations, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without experience with the specifics of Laravel migrations: When you do migrations on the same server there should be no problem, so long as the permissions are also migrated, because the `webappuser` is available cluster-wide.

When migrating to a different server you need to create the user on that new server and set the permissions for all migrated objects. You basically have two ways to do that.

The first is to set default privileges on the tables in the schema before you migrate or `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sch_name TO webappuser` after the migration. Default privileges are set with:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA sch_name
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO webappuser;
```

Both commands are fully SQL-standard compliant so you should have no problems across compliant architectures.

Keep in mind that any other tables created in the same schema will also have privileges set for `webappuser`. Setting privileges this way for an "untrusted" user (the person using the web application) is not recommended in a production environment because of potential privilege leaks; in a development environment it may be acceptable.

The second - which I would favour personally - is to write a stored procedure that sets the appropriate permissions. Do the migration, run the stored procedure once and you should be up-and-running. This gives you more control over the permission granting. The procedure could be something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION grant_webapp_privileges() RETURNS void AS $$
  -- Create the webappuser, if necessary
  CREATE ROLE webappuser LOGIN;

  -- Grant privileges on all required objects
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE table1 TO webappuser;
  ...
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

On the master database you simply need to keep the stored procedure up-to-date when you create or drop new relations. If Laravel supports insertion of code blocks not in the schema you are migrating, you can make the above procedure an anonymous code block that gets executed after the migration.

(As an aside, I NEVER give `webappuser`-like roles CRUD access. Instead I always provide access through views that hide some of the underlying data model specifics, such as a `person` having an `address`, `contact_information` and other details; the view serves it all up in one big row. That way you can easily change the underlying relations and update the view, rather than having to tweak your web application. Same principle really as OOP and easier to manage privileges.)

Comment: Migrations are designed to put database structure changes into the source-code repository as application code. That way all instances of the app will have the correct database structure.  Therefore, migrations must be designed so that they are exactly the same on all servers, without any prior knowledge of what the server looks like.  The only thing that the migration runner knows is that it has permission to connect to a specific database.  That's why I can't run a server-specific procedure after migration - because it would have to be able to run on the developers' personal machines as well.

Comment: Since I can always count on having the existing schema (because the migrations require it to have been pre-created), I think I will have to go with your "set default privileges" option.  Just to be sure, are you referring to using [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)?  Can you expand your answer a bit with an example of this?

Comment: Regarding your aside: In this case, I chose to expose the tables because the table structure perfectly matches the application structure - in fact, this particular application is solely a thin REST API around the database.  There is also a second application that only SELECTs from the database which can use read-only views, but that one is not the subject of this question.  In any case, I'm not really sure how you could model Many-to-many relations using views in such a way as to make them simultaneously easily queryable and easily editable.

Comment: PROCEDURE doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, try FUNCTION.

Comment: @FrankHeikens My bad, I stand corrected. But the term PROCEDURE for the same type of object does actually exist, such as in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement and the `pg_proc` system catalog relation.